# Check free storage space with RNFetchBlob (VS. RNFS)?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native, react-native-fs, react-native-fetch-blob

I am currently working on a React-Native project using React-Native-FS ([RNFS](https://github.com/johanneslumpe/react-native-fs)). It appears that the project is not actively maintained and the developers of RNFS recommend to use React-Native-Fetch-Blob ([RNFetchBlob](https://github.com/wkh237/react-native-fetch-blob)). The latter is kind of satisfying (even though the FileSystem is offers less features than RNFS) and the downloading (`fetch`) is more simple.

However, I was using RNFS's `getFSInfo()` to retrieve the amount of free space on disk. Recently, RNFetchBlob released the `df()` feature that basically does the same. However, I do not have the same results :

```
// RNFS
{
  totalSpace: 248828264448 (~ 248 GBytes)
  freeSpace: 216244088832 (~ 216 GBytes)
}

// RNFetchBlob
{
  free: 1495726032 (~ 1.5 GBytes)
  total: -279838720 (~ -279 MBytes)
}
```

What does explain the difference between the two ? Why is RNFetchBlob's last value a negative one ? There is no documentation relative to `RNFetchBlob.fs.df()` and looking at the source code didn't help me to spot the difference.

**PS**: I am using xcode's emulator; the reason could be that RNFS checks on **laptop** storage and RNFetchBlob checks on **emulator**'s ?